# Swift Mailer Error 500

Tags: php, email, send, swiftmailer

Hello I'm coming to you because I have a problem with a feature SwiftMailer PHP, indeed the sending function does not work and the email does not look (server OVH), but locally it works perfectly. I tried to find some errors by putting several die (), and it would seem that the problem comes from the line $ result = $ mailer-> send ($ message);
I do not understand the difference between the local and the production if not the connection (address that I recovered on OVH and mdp that I defined myself)
I would have liked more information on this and help to solve my problem, thank you!

```
<?php
session_start();


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost'){
  $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.mailtrap.io', 25))
    ->setUsername('*****')
    ->setPassword('*****');
}
else{

  $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('SSL0.OVH.NET', 587))
    ->setUsername('contact@matheozeller.fr')
    ->setPassword('Password');
  }

  $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);



  $errors = array(); // on crée une vérif de champs
  if(empty($_POST['Nom'])) {// on verifie l'existence du champ et d'un contenu
    $errors ['Nom'] = "Vous n'avez pas renseigné votre nom";
  }
  if(!array_key_exists('Email', $_POST) || $_POST['Email'] == '' || !filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {// on verifie existence de la clé
    $errors ['Email'] = "Vous n'avez pas renseigné votre email";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['Sujet'])) {// on verifie l'existence du champ et d'un contenu
    $errors ['Sujet'] = "Vous n'avez pas renseigné l'objet du message";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['Message'])) {
    $errors ['Message'] = "Vous n'avez pas renseigné votre Message";
  }


  if(empty($errors) !== true ){ // si erreur on renvoie vers la page précédente
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;//on stocke les erreurs
    $_SESSION['inputs'] = $_POST;
    header('Location: contact.php');
  }else{
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $message = (new Swift_Message(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Sujet'])))
    ->setSubject(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Sujet']))
    ->setFrom([htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email']) => htmlspecialchars($_POST['Nom'])])
    ->setTo(['matheo.zeller@gmail.com'])
    ->setBody(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message']));

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    $_SESSION['success'] = 1;
  header('Location: contact.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: How can i do this ?

Comment: Check with your webhost on how to find the server error logs. For some systems, there's an error.log in one of the directories. For others, it's in `/var/log/apache/` or `/var/log/nginx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error say´s that your server have problems. But you can try to log php error to and you can compare the local used php version and the php version there you use on the server. Maybe you use an old version on the server.

Comment: PHP dev = 7.2 , PHP server = 7.2 , same versions , i already check it

Comment: ok, run the script in some limits? whats your max execution time and the memory limit ? (on the server)

Comment: :) its an apache? and have you access to the config files or its a regular webhosting?

Comment: i've only access to my settings host , and i use apache , yes

Comment: so its a webhosting and not your own server?
please go to your script via ftp and create in this folder a new file called .htaccess -> "." is importent.

content of the new .htaccess file:
###
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value memory_limit 256M
###
end of the file

you can test these settings with a php info file. Just create another php file like that:

phpinfo.php
<?php
phpinfo() 
?>

if you call this file fia browser you can see the settings

Comment: I'm on my father's host , so can't see these informations

Comment: I can't use default value for execution time ? 
The problem come from this parameter?

Comment: its possible, if we cant read the logs so we have to try, whtas the default value?